# How to add specific value in a cell when adding new row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is my little VBA code to add a row

```
Sub insert()
 Range("A2").EntireRow.insert
End Sub
```

I would like to add "hi@google.com" in every "L" cells when adding a new row.

I can't figure out how

I tried this but no luck :

```
Sub insert()
 Range("A2").EntireRow.insert
Cells(2, 12).Value = hi@google.com
End Sub
```

Comment: `"hi@google.com"`

Comment: Because you want add it in L column after inserting a new row .. When you insert a new row, the new row is active. So, `Cells(Activecell.Row, 12).Value = "hi@google.com"`